# How to compare time complexity performance of two programs

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, graph, time-complexity

I have two programs, and I need to compare the time complexity/performance of these two programs where `n` is in millions. How do I do that? I'm lost. Perhaps I am overthinking it. For both programs, running it only returns the ***nth*** value, so what data do I use?

Comment: you can count the number of steps for both programs

Comment: If you have access to the code you can do analysis from the code. Otherwise you need to run both the program with varying values of n , like n = 100k, 200K... 1 million... 10 million, then plot the graph

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out how. I've been overthinking it way too much. 
I do fib(1) graph value and time
Then fib(5)
Then 
Fib(10)
Fib(100)
Fib(1000)
Fib(10000)
Fib(100000)
Fib(1000000)
And then graph the seconds and nth value

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have to **sort** a million number of elements stored in array. You use any two different **algorithm** for sorting like- **bubble sort and merge sort**.

If you have `10^7` elements then `bubble sort` will sort in maximum `10^14` **steps** and `merge sort` will sort in maximum `4 x 10^8` **steps**. you can count the **number of steps** taken by both sorting algorithm.

EDIT: to generate and store random numbers

```
  #include <time.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #define SIZE 1000000
  int numbers[SIZE]

  void generate()
  {      
  srand(time(NULL));   // should only be called once
  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
   numbers[i]= rand();      // returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and RAND_MAX
  }
```

Comment: So I understand the complexity. I know one is o log n, and the other is o n, but my professor is asking me to graph it and idk how I can plot and graph it with one value? Storing 0-nth values in an array and writing the values to txt is kind of impractical lol

Comment: you don't have to write 5 million values, you can generate random number million times through program.

Comment: Oh, ok makes sense. Thanks!